# In Ansible is there a way to use with_items and host variables at the same time?

Tags: python, ansible

So I have 3 hosts I want to run a playbook on.  Each host needs 3 files (all with the same names).

the files are going to be

- lacpbond.100
- lacpbond.200
- lacpbond.300

Each file has a unique IP address that goes into it based on the vars/ file.

The task looks like this->

```
- name: configure subinterface bonds
  template: src="ifcfg-lacpbondsub.j2" dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lacpbond.{{item.vlan}}
  with_items:
    - { vlan: "100" }
    - { vlan: "200" }
    - { vlan: "300" }
  tags:
    - bonding
```

So the vars looks like this->

```
  server01:
    loopbacks:
      ipv4: "10.0.0.100"
    SVIS:
      100:
        ipv4: "192.168.0.1"
        prefix: "28"
      200:
        ipv4: "192.168.1.1"
        prefix: "28"
      300:
        ipv4: "192.168.2.1"
        prefix: "28"
```

Now here comes the problem.  I am not sure how to use with_items and vars in the same time so I can use with_items to defer which variable to use.... this would greatly simplify the complexity of the playbook

here is the template file->

```
{% set host = interfaces[ansible_hostname] -%}
{% set VLAN = item.vlan -%}

DEVICE=lacpbond.{{item.vlan}}
IPADDR={{host.SVIS.{{item.vlan}}.ipv4}}
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
VLAN=yes
```

So the above works obviously if I don't use the {{}} within another {{}}.  But you can see what I am trying.  I can use item.X by itself fine, and I can use anything from vars/ fine.  But I don't know how to do something like
host.SVIS[VLAN].ipv4....

is this possible?  Otherwise I will need 3 tasks with 3 templates.... and if i need more files this is not as scalable....

Comment: I'm confused here, because you're asking for `{{host.SVIS...`, but you're setting host to `interfaces[ansible_hostname]`, so it's just a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think so.  For example if my template is just this->
`
`{{item.vlan}},
{{host.SVIS.100.ipv4}}`



it will generate->
`100,
192.168.0.1`

But if I try either 
`{{host.SVIS[item.vlan].ipv4}}
{{interfaces[ansible_hostname].SVIS[item.vlan].ipv4}}`

it fails the same with->
`failed: [server01] (item={u'vlan': u'100'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"vlan": "100"}, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute u'100'"}

its only broken when i combine item variables with variables from that folder... I am trying to use with_items to choose items from /vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear (in part because of the issue I pointed out in my comment), but if I understand what you're asking, you can just do something like:

```
IPADDR={{host.SVIS[item.vlan].ipv4}}
```

See the [Variables](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables) section of the Jinja documentation, which says:

> The following lines do the same thing:
>
> ```
> {{ foo.bar }} 
> {{ foo['bar'] }}
> ```

**Update**

You are getting that error ("AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute u'100'") because the keys in your dictionary are integers, but the values of the `vlan` keys in your with_items loop are strings.  That is, `host.SVIS[100]` exists, but `hosts.SVIS['100']` does not exist.

Given this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    interfaces:
      server01:
          loopbacks:
            ipv4: "10.0.0.100"
          SVIS:
            100:
              ipv4: "192.168.0.1"
              prefix: "28"
            200:
              ipv4: "192.168.1.1"
              prefix: "28"
            300:
              ipv4: "192.168.2.1"
              prefix: "28"
    ansible_hostname: server01
  tasks:
    - name: configure subinterface bonds
      template:
        src: "ifcfg-lacpbondsub.j2"
        dest: ./ifcfg-lacpbond.{{item.vlan}}
      with_items:
        - { vlan: 100 }
        - { vlan: 200 }
        - { vlan: 300 }
      tags:
        - bonding
```

And this template:

```
{% set host = interfaces[ansible_hostname] -%}

DEVICE=lacpbond.{{item.vlan}}
IPADDR={{host.SVIS[item.vlan].ipv4}}
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
VLAN=yes
Raw
```

I get three files:

```
$ ls ifcfg-lacpbond.*
ifcfg-lacpbond.100  ifcfg-lacpbond.200  ifcfg-lacpbond.300
```

The content of each looks something like:

```
DEVICE=lacpbond.100
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
VLAN=yes
```

Comment: tried that and it does not work :(  Look at my comment response to your comment above

Comment: See my update, which explains the source of your error.

Comment: thank you so much, makes a lot of sense.  I think I assume the numbers were strings since there were in yml format with sub-variables.... guess I am silly